# MySQL version for RMySQL

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I am using MySQL and R, with the package RMySQL... (naturally)
After a computer update, and when loading RMySQL, I started getting this warning message:

```
RMySQL was compiled with MySQL 5.5.40 but loading MySQL 5.6.24 instead!
This may cause problems with your database connections.
Please install MySQL 5.5.40.
```

I would rather not have to downgrade MySQL, and was wondering if I should just compile RMySQL in order to use the newer version.  Still, I couldn't find how to do it, and therefore look for a more direct answer.

Best regards,

Comment: Did you try to remove and reinstall `RMySQL`?

Comment: `remove.packages` and `reinstall.packages` in R is the right solution. In addition, I needed to install `libmysqlclient_dev` from terminal.